# new to programming in C. why doesnt this variable updaate after -= operations?

Tags: c

```
int main() {
    int minutes = 245;
    double hours = (double) minutes / (double) 60.0;
    printf("%.2f\n", hours); // prints 4.08

    hours -= (double) 3.0; 
    int test = hours * .5;
    printf("%.2f", test);  // also prints 4.08 despite -= operator
}
```

Not sure if it has to do with pointers/memory address/how its being handled and how to fix this problem.

Comment: At the last printf, there is a warning by the compiler: `warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'int'` ... so make `test` a double instead, or do what the posted answer suggests.

Comment: As a side-note, literally none of your casts are necessary, nor desirable. `minutes / 60.0` will already produce a `double` (`60.0` *is* a `double`; if you used `60`, a cast would be needed to avoid truncating division; similarly, `3.0` is a `double`, so there's no point in casting it). Try to avoid casting unless you need a type conversion that won't occur automatically. Casts are one of the worst offenders in terms of creating the opportunity for runtime misbehavior that might have been caught at compile-time if not for the cast silencing the compiler's checks.

Comment: Do you have warnings enabled? You should've seen a compiler warning there.

Answer (score 3):

`test` is an `int`. Your `printf` format code, `f`, tells it you passed it a `double`. On many architectures/calling conventions (including standard x86-64 conventions), the variables are passed in completely different registers so it isn't even looking in the right place. On others, the variables might be passed in the same storage location (e.g. on the stack), but interpreting an `int` as a `double` would come up with gibberish (and when the `int` is half the size of a `double`, you'd read garbage bits for half of it).

Change it to:

```
printf("%.2d", test);
```

to make it expect `test` to be an `int` properly, or leave the `printf` unchanged and change `test`'s declaration to make it a `double` instead of an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() {
    int minutes = 245;
    double hours = (double) minutes / (double) 60.0;
```

`60.0` is already a `double` literal, so no need to cast it.  And also no need to cast `minutes` to `double` as the division will be made on doubles, as one double operand forces the other to be converted to `double` (and so, `minutes` will be converted to `double` before dividing)

```
    printf("%.2f\n", hours); // prints 4.08
```

this is correct, nothing to say.

```
    hours -= (double) 3.0;
```

`hours` gets changed to `1.08`.

```
    int test = hours * .5;
```

and `test` becomes half that quantity (0.54) converted to `int` (because it is so declared), or `0`.

```
    printf("%.2f", test);  // also prints 4.08 despite -= operator
```

This invokes **Undefined behaviour**, as you are telling `printf()` to use a `double` data (as of the `%.2f` format specifier), but you are passing it an `int`  (and, as floating point numbers are normally handled in some register on the math coprocessor while integers are located in some integer cpu register, it doesn't get the contents of `hours` (which is 1.08 by now) but the previous contents of some coprocessor register, completely unrelated.  You have been warned by the compiler of this fact because your parameter doesn't match the format specifier (this happens if you did `#include <stdio.h>`) or (if you didn't) you are warned because of using a function (`printf`) without being declared (which is very bad habit and error prone)

The code below will show you the contents of both, `hours` and `test`: (and please, never forget to `#include <stdio.h>`, as it is needed if you use `printf()`)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int minutes = 245;
    double hours = minutes / 60.0;
    printf("hours=%.2f\n", hours); // prints 4.08

    hours -= 3.0; /* hours becomes 1.08 */
    int test = hours * .5; /* test will become the integer part of hours/2.0 -> 0.54 */
    printf("hours=%.2f\ntest=%d\n", hours, test);
}
```

that will produce:

```
$ a.out
hours=4.08
hours=1.08
test=0
```

as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is working fine. The variable `hours` is updating. As you mentioned, you are new to C programming. You might not know how to use a debugger. So, for starters, I suggest you try putting prints after each statement. It will help you to understand the code flow better.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( ) {
    int minutes = 245;
    double hours = (double) minutes / (double) 60.0;
    printf("%lf\n", hours); //4.083333

    hours -= (double)3.0; 
    printf("%lf\n", hours); // 1.083333   
    int test = hours * 0.5;
    double test1 = hours * 0.5;
    printf("%lf\n", test);//0.000000
    printf("%lf", test1); // 0.541667   
}
```